# Chrome and IE doesn't work with SameSite attribute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies

i try to learn how to set cookies but when i try to open my page with chrome/IE is like there are no cookies .. but in firefox all work ! i have try to remove "sameSite attribute et secure" and that work on all navigators but i have an error message in firefox like : "you need to give a sameSite attribute etc etc .."
Someone can help me ?
this is my code

```
 function creerCookie(result){

  document.cookie = 'Cookie='+result+ '; SameSite:"Lax";secure '
  console.log(document.cookie)
}

function getCookie (name){
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}


let body = document.body

let kiki =  getCookie('Cookie')
console.log("voila :"+kiki)

if (kiki==="test1"){
    body.style.background = "red"
}else if (kiki === "test2"){
    body.style.background = "green"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `Secure` attribute. From [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), we can know that

> A cookie with the `Secure` attribute is sent to the server only with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol, never with unsecured HTTP.
>
> Insecure sites (with `http:` in the URL) can't set cookies with the `Secure` attribute.

You can host your test page via `https` then the code will work in IE and Chrome.

In IE:
[image]
In Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but you said is not possible to create cookies on http expect on localhost . but I'm on localhost ...

Comment: I also test on localhost with `http` and `https`. In my research, it doesn't work with `http` but works with `https` on localhost. I'm also confused about the **(except on localhost)** in the document. I just copied the sentence from the doc and the doc maybe not 100% right. You can have a try, it works with `https`.

Comment: ok thanks no problem about the document and thanks too for your time ! Then i need to create a server https on node js that's right ?

Comment: I don't know what server you're using, if it's node.js, Yes , just serve your page via `https` protocol.